# Perplexing Output of C language program using Turbo C++ 3.0 compiler

Tags: c

Concerning my determination for output.It's **1 40 1** While using C it displays output as **0 41 1** How's that possible?What wrong step I'm going into?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    int n,a,b;

    n = 400;
    a = n % 100; //remainder operation
    b = n / 10; //division operation
    n = n % 10; //remainder operation

    printf("%d %d %d",n++,++b,++a); //post-,pre-,pre- increment used
    getch(); 
}
```

Comment: The output should be `0 41 1`. If this outputs `1 40 1` for you, your compiler is broken.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Uh, heck, you are right (how embarassing;-). I just saw the multiple increment operators; thanks for pointing me at this. Sorry to OP! Still the signature of `main` is invalid.

Comment: @FUZxxl Can you please demonstrate the flow of this program,if my brain compiler is broken.

Comment: Use a working compiler. 1) Don't use a C++ compiler for C code anyway. 2) Turbo-C++ is ancient and not standard compliant (has it ever been actually?

Comment: @JohnCounter Sure thing, give me a second.

Comment: @JohnCounter: How about installing a working compiler and try yourself?

Comment: @FUZxxl said my determination isn't true.So don't you think that using another compiler to compile this program is useless?

Comment: @JohnCounter I'm not suggesting you to use a different compiler, your compiler seems to produce the right output. See my answer for what values a, b, and n have during the programs execution.

Comment: @FUZxxl oh sorry there I was saying it to Olaf

Comment: I'm considering precisely,wait please.

Answer (score 1):

What your compiler prints is correct. Here is the program flow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    int n,a,b;

    n = 400;     // n has value 400
    a = n % 100; // a has value 0
    b = n / 10;  // b has value 40
    n = n % 10;  // n has value 0

    // n++ evaluates to  0, afterwards n has the value  1
    // ++b evaluates to 41, afterwards b has the value 41
    // ++a evaluates to  1, afterwards a has the value  1
    printf("%d %d %d",n++,++b,++a);
    // Thus, 0 41 1 is printed.
    getch(); 
}
```

Notice especially that the postfix-incrememnt operator `n++` returns the value of `n` unchanged and then changes `n`. That's why `0` is printed in the first column.

Comment: Here ++b and ++a are inrementing after the evaluation of assignment expressions,is that correct?

Comment: No, it's the other way round.

Comment: I think my concepts what I learned concerning my college syllabus book about unary operators post- and pre- fix are devastated.Can you provide any link to study of these two.I may be able to understand clearly if you have any benefical URL link? I'm already so much baffled..I'll revise it and then consider your program again.Because whichever output i'm thinking where unary operators is always an 'inverse' of it. Like this one I just posted.So I need to calm down and then return back to see your flow of code.

Comment: Read any half decent C tutorial. This topic really is not that complicated.

Comment: you may be a veteran guy,but I'm just a beginner.

Comment: @JohnCounter Yes, I know. I received knowledge in C by reading books and tutorials, rarely by asking questions. Good C tutorials contain much better explanations of these operators than I can spell out here and now.